# How to change root directory for sftp user in ubuntu

Tags: directory, user-management

Hi I would like to allow a client access to the server via filezilla with SFTP.

I have the username, home directory and group set up.

This currently brings them to their home directory with appropriate permissions....

```
Match group filetransfer
    ChrootDirectory %h
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

I tried to change `%h` to /var/www/html/mysite but I get an error `Error initialising channel: Error reading socket.`

EDIT, just using the group for now as I will be adding more users